# inconsistent results with left shift operator (<<)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, unsigned-integer

I am learning bit manipulation using C. I encountered a problem when writing a program that converts a binary to decimal, particularly in the for loop of the program. The following is my code:

```
unsigned int binary_to_uint(const char *b)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    int i, len;
    if (!b)
        return (0);
    len = strlen(b);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (b[i] == '1')
        {
            result += 2 << (i-1); /*where my issue is*/
        }
        else if (b[i] == '0')
            continue;
        else
            return (0);
    }
    return (9);
}
```

I tried debugging and I realized my problem was originating from the **if** statement

I therefore did some experiment with the code in the **if*** statement:

```
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    int i = 0;
    printf("result of 2 << (%d - 1): %d\n", i, 2 << (i - 1));
    printf("result of 2 << (0 - 1): %d", 2 << (0 - 1));

    return 0;
}
```

In the first printf, displays **result of 2 << (0 - 1): 0** in the console, while
in the second printf, displays **result of 2 << (0 - 1): 1** in the console.
My expectation is that both printf should display the exact same thing, that is the value of ***2 << -1 is 1***, however that is not the case. Can someone please help me understand what is going on. why did the use of the variable i change the outcome of the shift operator to 0?

Comment: There are two `%d` in this format string but I only see one argument. `printf("result of 2 << (%d - 1): %d\n", 2 << (i - 1));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand operand of the `<<` or `>>` operators is required to be non-negative.  Using a negative value for this operand triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Because of this, you can't use a negative value to shift in the opposite direction.

This is detailed in section 6.5.7p3 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
> of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **If the value of
> the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width
> of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.**

In your particular case, undefined behavior is manifesting as different results between using `i-1` and `0-1` for the right operand.

Instead of shifting `2` by `i-1` places, instead shift `1` by `i` places:

```
result += 1 << i;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `b[i]`  is equal to `'1'` then you need to shift the unsigned constant `1u` instead of the signed constant 2 and using `len - i - 1` instead of  `i-1`. Moreover the last expression can be negative when `i` is equal tp `0`.

```
    if (b[i] == '1')
    {
        result += 1u << len - i - 1;
    }
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int binary_to_uint( const char *b )
{
    unsigned int result = 0;

    size_t len = strlen( b );

    if (CHAR_BIT * sizeof( unsigned int ) < len)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (b[i] == '1')
            {
                result += 1u << len - i - 1;
            }
            else if (b[i] != '0')
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *b = "1111";

    printf( "\"%s\" = %u\n", b, binary_to_uint( b ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
"1111" = 15
```